# Jquery doesnot bind events to ajax added dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an ajax function that loads the content of 4 checkboxes as follows:

```
$.ajax({
url : some url..,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(data) {
    buildCheckboxes(data);
    },
error : function(data) {
            do something...
    }
});
```

build checkboxes methods does something like this:

```
function updateNotificationMethods(items) {
    var html = [];
    $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        htmlBuilder = [];
        htmlBuilder.push("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-class' name='somename' value='");
        htmlBuilder.push(item.id);
        htmlBuilder.push("'");
        htmlBuilder.push("/>&nbsp;");
        htmlBuilder.push(item.name);
        htmlBuilder.push("<br/><br/>")
        html.push(htmlBuilder.join(''));
    });
    $("#div").html(html.join(''));
}
```

i have also an event binder that should be triggered when checkbox value changes:

```
$(".checkbox-class").change(function() {
alert("change");
 });
```

it works if i have the checkboxes html in the source (i.e. static) as opposed to the set up i have here, where i dynamically load the data from server.

is there something i can do so that binding take place timely?

peace!

Comment: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

Comment: ok the problem was solved by "live" but consider using template for building html on the fly. jquery.tmpl or underscore.js are great for this job

Comment: @melanke thanks for the tip, I will sure use it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the element is not present when you bind your handler.

Try this:

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '.checkbox-class', function() {
    alert("change");
});
```

Or if you are using an older version of jQuery (less than 1.7) ...

```
$( '.checkbox-class' ).live( function() {
    alert("change");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! so I assume on waits till all dom is loaded?

Comment: This is the correct way to use delegation for the problem. Although it would be ideal to find a more specific container than `document` (for the OP to do)

Comment: @Ibrahim Yes, you still need to put this inside of `document.ready`

Comment: And it looks like the element `#div` is the correct parent that can be used.

Comment: @Ibrahim No, not really. The reason this works is that the handler is assigned to the document (which IS present when the bind is called). Then when the event propagates up to that element it is applied to any elements that match the selector (whether added dynamically or loaded by default).

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes are not available while you are binding the events.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AL59x/2/)

Assuming that element with id div is present while binding the event.

```
$("#div").on("change",".checkbox-class",function() {
     alert("change");
 });
```

Comment: Nope. It would be `$('.parent-of-checkbox').on('change', '.checkblox-class', function()...);`

Comment: @KevinBoucher Nope. That would only bind to existing `checkbox-class` elements at the time of its call; any dynamically created elements with that class would not have that callback to the change event.

Comment: @KevinBoucher What are you talking about? No it can't be either. It can **only** be the delegating way, which is what Shmiddty is saying. Sushil's answer is no different than normal `bind`

Comment: From jQuery docs: `Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().`

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yes, and your answer is correct, but you **need** to use 3 arguments for `on` like you are in order to have the effect that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$(".checkbox-class").change(function() {
alert("change");
});
```

**do not establishes a continuous and on-going rule**, instead, this code attaches an event manager (in this case to the change event) to each matching DOM object that exists at the moment it is executed.
If you want you can re-execute this code (or one similar and narrow) each time you add checkboxes to the DOM.